# Is image or file being always downloaded from Google Cloud Storage on click?

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Please help me to understand the following, I have a node.js app which I want to run on Google Cloud App Engine, this app will contain some images which are planned to be stored on Google Cloud Storage. On my sample app once I upload an image and get a url (mediaLink or selfLink) image is being downloaded.

Why is that? Each download each click costs money I understand google, but is there any way to make url just show images NOT to be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving a file from Google Cloud Storage is the same as displaying it. Both action require transferring the content of the image to the device for display or saving.

The action of displaying an image or popping up a save as dialog is controlled by HTTP headers. For example if you have the HTTP header `content-type` set incorrectly (not as an image) then some browsers will save the file. If you want your image files to be displayed as images set the headers correctly for the type of picture. For PNG files set the header `contenty-type: image/png`.

You can also force a download with the `content-disposition: attachment` header.

In summary, it does not matter if you are displaying an image or saving it to local storage, it will cost you money. Both actions requiring downloading (transferring) the contents of the file across the Internet.